# github v3 api equivalent of /v2/json/commits/list

Tags: github, github-api

I am using /v2/json/commits/list/:user/:repo/:branch to list the commits for a branch.  Two problems with this:

- it only returns 35 items at a time
- it's part of the v2 api, which is deprecated (the v3 api is documented as beta, so I guess I'm darned if I do and darned if I do newer)

What is the v3 equivalent of the above v2 api?

I looked at /repos/:user/:repo/commits and /repos/:user/:repo/git/commits:

- /repos/:user/:repo/commits takes an sha or a branch as an argument, but only returns 1 commit if it is passed in
- /repos/:user/:repo/git/commits does not take a branch as an argument
- if I don't specify the branch, neither one makes it clear which branch a given commit was on.

Is there a v3 equivalent, or am I stuck with v2 for now?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the github v3 API on retrieving a single commit, the following worked for me:

```
/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits/{branch}
```